# Expression to retrieve name of next underlying activated layer

Tags: qgis, layers, expression

I have a QGIS project with vector layer that contains many atlas features and then I have many different raster files "under" it and depending on what I want to export, I activate them.
However, every time I change the raster layer, I have to adjust certain fields in the vector layer because they contain the information that defines the name of the exports.
I would like to automate that. I was trying to find a way where I can configure a virtual field in a vector shapefile that automatically retrieves the name of the next underlying activated raster layer. I am fine with just getting the full name of the raster, i can then extract the rest myself.

I could not find a possibility to do that, because I can only point an expression to a specific layer. The specific layer would have to be the next underlying raster which is activated.

Comment: If you wish to also ask about PyQGIS then please do that in a separate question that includes a code attempt.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is PyQGIS. A solution for a normal QGIS expression is preferred. I would love to make a PyQGIS attempt but do not have the time for it right now. I have taken a look at available QGIS expressions but could not identify any one that seemed like it might do what. In the expressions I can only point to a specific layer, but I am looking for a possibility to say "use the information of the next activated underlying raster layer".

Comment: Maybe creating a virtual raster out of all your raster layers solves the problem? Then you have just one raster left you can refer to.

Comment: @Babel Do you have an example for that? I never worked with virtual layers before.

Comment: Vitrual raster is **not** the same as virtual raster. Virtual raster simply "merges" different rasters like a mosaic to one single, large raster. See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#build-virtual-raster

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean. No, the rasters all more or less cover the same area just show different stuff. So they are all overlapping each other. I just activate one, then export my atlas features with pre-defined extents and then I move on to the next one. Right now, I adjust the important information in my extents-vector layer, export the atlas features and move on. I was just wondering if there is a more automated way or if I have to do it manually :)